# Problema ao usar Mobx e Observerlist

Tags: flutter

Olá, boa tarde!

Estou tentando fazer uma lista de checkbox (CheckboxListTile) usando o mobx, porém, sempre que clico na caixinha para marcar ou desmarcar tenho que usar o flutter reload ou o setState para atualizar os dados.

O mobx não está atualizando automaticamente utilizando o observer, não sei porque. Poderiam me ajudar?

**Meu model:**

```
part 'ItemComplementoModel.g.dart';
 
class ItemComplementoModel = _ItemComplementoModel with _$ItemComplementoModel;
 
abstract class _ItemComplementoModel with Store{
 
  @observable
  ObservableList<Map<String, dynamic>> listaItens = ObservableList<Map<String, dynamic>>();
 
  @action
  void addItem(Map<String, dynamic> novoItem){
    listaItens.add(novoItem);
  }
 
  @action
  void marcarItem(int indice, bool marcou, ItemComplemento itemComplemento){
    print("marcou");
    //listaItens[indice]["marcou"] = marcou;
 
      print(listaItens);
      print("depois...");
      listaItens[indice]["marcou"] = marcou;
      print(listaItens);
 
  }
 
}
```

Meu observer:

```
_parteItemComplemento(int indice, ItemComplemento itemComplemento){

  return Observer(
    builder: (_){
      return CheckboxListTile(
        onChanged: (marcou){
          //setState(() {
          //_listaItensComplementos[indice]["marcou"] = marcou;
          itemComplementoModel.marcarItem(indice, marcou, itemComplemento);
          print("marcou: ${marcou}");
          //_saveData();
          //});
        },
        title: Text(itemComplemento.nome),
        //value: _listaItensComplementos[indice]["marcou"],
        value: itemComplementoModel.listaItens[indice]["marcou"],
        secondary: CircleAvatar(
          child: Icon(
              itemComplementoModel.listaItens[indice]["marcou"]
                  ? Icons.check
                  : Icons.error
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Se você está usando o _MobX_ não é necessário utilizar o _setState()_... O seu problema, acredito eu dando uma olhada por cima, acho que é porque você está utilizando uma _ObservableList_ do tipo _Map_, a lista é atualizada quando a referência de um objeto dela muda, e no seu caso você só está mudando um valor de um objeto do _Map_, sendo assim a referência do mesmo não se altera. Se você mudar o _marcarItem_, por exemplo, para: `listaItens[indice] = {"marcou": false};` ou `listaItens[indice] = {"marcou": true};` deve funcionar.

Comment: Perfeito! Problema resolvido, muito obrigado.

Comment: Consegui um tempinho para produzir uma resposta mais detalhada! De uma olhada depois.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente, quando você utiliza o *MobX*, dentro do Widget *Observer* não é preciso utilizar o *setState()*.

### ObserverList

Esse tipo de lista, vai ficar escutando a alteração na referência de cada objeto que ela contém; Assim toda vez que um objeto ser alterado, o Observer vai ser notificado para atualização em tela.

### Resolução

No seu caso, você está trabalhando com o seguinte

```
@observable
ObservableList<Map<String, dynamic>> listaItens = ObservableList<Map<String, dynamic>>();
```

E ao clicar em algum *CheckBox* você dispara a seguinte função:

```
  @action
  void marcarItem(int indice, bool marcou, ItemComplemento itemComplemento){
      listaItens[indice]["marcou"] = marcou;    
  }
```

O seu problema é que da forma que está sendo feito, a sua lista não está notificando a alteração do item pois a referência do mesmo não foi altera.
O que você está fazendo é simplesmente mudar o valor de um objeto do *Map*.

Para que funcione corretamente, do jeito que está feito ai, tu precisa fazer um pequeno ajuste:

```
  @action
  void marcarItem(int indice, bool marcou, ItemComplemento itemComplemento) {
      if (marcou)
        listaItens[indice] = {"marcou": true};
      else
        listaItens[indice] = {"marcou": false};    
  }
```

Dessa forma, a lista irá notificar o *Observer* que houve uma mudança na referência do objeto e que é necessário atualizar o layout.

Comment: Sua resposta foi simplesmente perfeita, Matheus.

Comment: Uma última dúvida, estou fazendo agora com um objeto e estou tendo o mesmo problema. A minha lista só atualiza se eu utilizar o setState, o que não deveria acontecer. Como posso notificar a lista no caso de um objeto? Sou novo por aqui e não sei se deveria criar uma nova pergunta.

Comment: O que seria esse "Objeto"? Você trocou o `ObserverList<Map<String, dynamic>>` por `ObserverList<UmaClasse>`?

Comment: Exatamente. Meu marcarItem ficou mais ou menos assim: ItemComplemento itemComplemento = listaItens[indice];
    print(itemComplemento.nome);
    itemComplemento.marcado = marcou;

Comment: O interessante é que cada questão seja uma pergunta. Mas no teu caso te aconselho antes, dar uma olhada em um repositório meu do GitHub [Campo Minado](https://github.com/matheusrmribeiro/desafio_campominado). Lá trabalho com um esquema parecido, você vai conseguir encontrar um exemplo nos arquivos [FieldModel](https://github.com/matheusrmribeiro/desafio_campominado/blob/master/lib/src/domain/model/field_model.dart) e [MinesweeperController](https://github.com/matheusrmribeiro/desafio_campominado/blob/master/lib/src/app/controller/minesweeper_controller.dart)

Comment: Ok Matheus, farei outra pergunta. Mas agradeço pela sua atenção.

Answer (score -1):

**Resposta perfeita, Matheus! Muito Obrigado!**

Mas no caso, agora necessito de usar um objeto/classe no lugar do array para pegar também outros atributos de forma mais fácil e organizada.

**Então meu model ficou assim:**

```
abstract class _ItemComplementoModel with Store{

  @observable
  ObservableList<ItemComplemento> listaItens = ObservableList<ItemComplemento>();

  @action
  void addItem(ItemComplemento novoItem){
    listaItens.add(novoItem);
  }

  @action
  void marcarItem(int indice, bool marcou, CarrinhoModel carrinhoModel){

    ItemComplemento itemComplemento = listaItens[indice];
    print(itemComplemento.nome);
    itemComplemento.marcado = marcou;

  }

}
```

**E meu observer:**

```
_parteItemComplemento(int indice, ItemComplemento itemComplemento){
    return Observer(
      builder: (_){
        return CheckboxListTile(
          onChanged: (marcou){
            itemComplementoModel.marcarItem(indice, marcou, carrinhoModel);
            print("marcou ${marcou}");
          },
          title: Text(itemComplemento.nome),
          value: itemComplementoModel.listaItens[indice].marcado,
          secondary: CircleAvatar(
            child: Icon(
                itemComplementoModel.listaItens[indice].marcado
                    ? Icons.check
                    : Icons.error
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Porém, continuo com o mesmo problema anterior, a lista só é atualizada se utilizo o setState, coisa que não deveria acontecer.

Comment: Esse é um espaço para respostas apenas, para "outros problemas" crie novas perguntas ou se for relacionado ao problema principal edite a sua pergunta.

Comment: Criei essa nova pergunta, Matheus: [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/490862/problema-observerlist-mobx). Se puder me ajudar ficarei muito grato, creio que seja também alterar só uma linha de código, porém, não estou conseguindo chegar a uma solução como a anterior.