# Problema ObserverList + Mobx

Tags: flutter, dart

**Olá!**

Estou tentando fazer uma lista de checkbox (CheckboxListTile) usando o mobx, porém, sempre que clico na caixinha para marcar/desmarcar tenho que usar o `flutter reload` ou o `setState` para atualizar os dados.

O mobx não está atualizando automaticamente utilizando o observer. Não sei porque. Poderiam me ajudar?

**Meu model ficou assim:**

```
abstract class _ItemComplementoModel with Store{

  @observable
  ObservableList<ItemComplemento> listaItens = ObservableList<ItemComplemento>();

  @action
  void addItem(ItemComplemento novoItem){
    listaItens.add(novoItem);
  }

  @action
  void marcarItem(int indice, bool marcou, CarrinhoModel carrinhoModel){

    ItemComplemento itemComplemento = listaItens[indice];
    print(itemComplemento.nome);
    itemComplemento.marcado = marcou;

  }

}
```

**E meu observer:**

```
_parteItemComplemento(int indice, ItemComplemento itemComplemento){
    return Observer(
      builder: (_){
        return CheckboxListTile(
          onChanged: (marcou){
            itemComplementoModel.marcarItem(indice, marcou, carrinhoModel);
            print("marcou ${marcou}");
          },
          title: Text(itemComplemento.nome),
          value: itemComplementoModel.listaItens[indice].marcado,
          secondary: CircleAvatar(
            child: Icon(
                itemComplementoModel.listaItens[indice].marcado
                    ? Icons.check
                    : Icons.error
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: Já tentou fazer o mesmo procedimento que lhe indiquei na sua outra pergunta? Dentro da função `marcarItem()`, faça tudo que é preciso com o item e no final faça `listaItens[indice] = itemComplemento`? Não é a melhor abordagem mas deve funcionar.

Comment: Sim, tentei fazer desta forma, o problema é que a lista não atualiza igual aquela outra utilizando o Map.

Comment: Naquela deu certo, nessa aparentemente não.  Achei estranho! Me indica alguma outra abordagem para tentar?

Comment: Te aconselho, dar uma olhada em um repositório meu do GitHub [Campo Minado](https://github.com/matheusrmribeiro/desafio_campominado). Lá trabalho com um esquema parecido, você vai conseguir encontrar um exemplo nos arquivos [FieldModel](https://github.com/matheusrmribeiro/desafio_campominado) e [MinesweeperController](https://github.com/matheusrmribeiro/desafio_campominado/blob/master/lib/src/app/controller/minesweeper_controller.dart)

Comment: Dei uma olhada, porém não consegui chegar a uma solução para esse problema.

Answer (score 2):

Eu dei como exemplo um projeto meu do GitHub e é nele que vou me basear [Campo Minado](https://github.com/matheusrmribeiro/desafio_campominado).

Para que seu código fique organizado de uma melhor forma e tenha toda a reatividade que deseja, você precisa que as informações tratadas no *CheckBox* sejam também uma *Store* do *MobX*.

**Classe de controle do *CheckBox***

É necessário que você crie uma classe para controlar os dados do mesmo, faça o seguinte:

```
class ItemModel = _FieldModel with _$FieldModel;

abstract class _ItemModel with Store {
  
  _FieldModel({
    this.checked
  });

  @observable
  bool checked = false;
  
}
```

Então modifique teu método existente:

```
abstract class _ItemComplementoModel with Store{

  @observable
  ObservableList<ItemModel> listaItens = ObservableList<ItemModel>();

  @action
  void addItem(ItemModel novoItem){
    listaItens.add(novoItem);
  }

  @action
  void marcarItem(int indice, bool marcou, CarrinhoModel carrinhoModel){

    ItemModel itemModel = listaItens[indice];
    print(itemModel.nome);
    itemModel.marcado = marcou;

  }

}
```

### Explicação

O Widget *Observer* vai ficar escutando todo e qualquer *Observable* que estiver sendo utilizado dentro dele, dessa forma assim que um deles sofrer alterações, as mesmas serão aplicadas no layout.

Por isso que é necessário que a simples classe *ItemComplemento* vire um *Store*, o *ItemModel*. E dessa forma, não é necessário ficar realizando alterações na referência dos objetos da lista.